# Proper way to get indexes of a UITableViewCell in response to a button click which sits in a tableview within tableview?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Screenshot of the app:

[image: this is a screenshot of the app]

I have an 'x' button to delete a TableViewCell which is in a table within a table. On click of the button, I would like to remove the cell, so I need to know the 2 indexes of the button click, the row if the first table view, and then within that tableview the row of the cell which the button was clicked. All I have is the sender.

So to be a bit clearer, in the screenshot, if someone clicks the x under the ford fiesta, I need to get indexpath 0 for the "subtableview" and 1 for the tableview, and that way I know to delete this element from the table datasource.

I do it successfully by doing:

```
var cell = sender.superview
while (cell != nil) && !((cell?.isKind(of: CustomCell.self))!) {
    cell = cell?.superview
}
    let tbl = cell?.superview as! UITableView
    let indexPath = tbl.indexPath(for: (cell as? UITableViewCell)!
)
```

The stupid thing is I have to do it twice, once to find the index of the cell within the "sub"tableview, and then again to find the index of the "subtableview" within the tableview.

Is there a better way to do this? Isnt there a way to get the buttonClick to get the didSelectRowAt to fire and add the sender object to it (so I know that a button was clicked as opposed to the cell being selected)?

*EDIT* I forgot to mention that the first tableview opens and closes on click, so the main tableview has 2 different cell types, one closed (so no nested tableview) and then onselect of a row from that tableview, the cell is replaced with a detailed cell which has another tableview inside it, thats why sectioned tableview isnt a solution (to the best of my knowledge, I'm new here)

Comment: First, what is need of nesting!!!! mostly everything is possible with single tableview or collectionview. You need to rethink on it!!!

Comment: you should use only one tableview dude.not separate for each record and its sub record user number of sections and view for section methods

Comment: Posted sceenshot is a textbook example of a single `UITableView` with sections

Comment: @mag_zbc i edited the post, it wasnt clear that the main tableview is made of 2 types of cells, one standard and the other detailed, which opens up onselect of a row. so a sectioned tableview I dont think would be efficient here (I could obviously play with the visibility of the "detail" sections, but I understand that using 2 cell types is more efficient

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to use closures. You set up your cell with a closure and then call it. Pretty much like this:

```
class CellWithClosure: UITableViewCell {

    var button: UIButton = UIButton()

    var closureForButton: (Void) -> Void
    func setupCell(closureForButton: @escaping (Void) -> Void) {
        self.closureForButton = closureForButton
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
    }

    @objc func buttonAction() {
        closureForButton()
    }    
}
```

Comment: Ok, that would work if I just needed to close the cell, but OnClick of the X button I also need to send an api request with information I hold in the datasource in position [indexPath] so I still need to get the indexPath somehow...

Comment: you can pass that object also in the setupCell method, I hope that is a class. Is your network layer separated so you can create an instance of your endpoint thing inside the cell or the better approach than should be in my opinion is to use mvvm and based on your data source to create the cell's view model and these cell vie models to have a similar closure with your object as a parameter

Comment: the datasource is a class yes, which holds as a property the actual data (which is another object) and handles the tableView delegates and builds the cells accordingly... you think I should pass the datasource into the cell and hold it as a property?! i new to mvvm but doesnt sound right, but neither does passing in the actual data object... what do you mean?